# Set backgroundImage array mapping using React inline styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my folder structure:

```
src
   --Assets/
            --pug.svg
            --scss.svg
   --Layouts/
            --Skills/
                    --Skills.js
   --App.js
```

My array

```
const skills = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Pug',
    image: 'url(../../Assets/pug.svg)'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'SCSS',
    image: 'url(../../Assets/scss.svg)'
  }
```

In Skills.js I want to set the backgroundImage using React's inline styles, but it doesn't work.
I don't get any error, just the backgroundImage doesn't show up.

```
{
    skills.map(skill => (
        <motion.div className='column' key={skill.id} variants={container}>
           <div className='skill'>
             <div className='skill-image' style={{ backgroundImage: `${skill.image}`  }}/>
             <h3>{skill.title}</h3>
           </div>
        </motion.div>
      ))
   }
```

Comment: Just to be clear - `background-image` is attached to `skill-image` element, but simply not shown?

Comment: Yes, it's attached when I open my console, but it doesn't show up.

Comment: Is this Create-React-App project or, if not, what bundler do you use?

Comment: Yes, I'm using create-react-app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use relative paths in `background-image` directly. Those won't be resolvable from browser perspective as modules aren't preserved, but bundled together instead.

Now, to make it work you can:
a) move your assets (images) to /public and then replace their paths with `/pug.svg` and `/scss.svg`.
b) import images directly in your JavaScript files using `import`

First option uses special /public directory. Assets located there can be reached by browser. See https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/ for details.

As for importing assets directly, this heavily relies on your bundler (Webpack). It will resolve those files while building and attach them to the output. If you want to know more visit https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files.

Look at following code block. I've replaced your relative paths with URLs returned from import statements. You can look them up using `console.log` to see the difference.

```
import pugImage from '../../Assets/pug.svg';
import scssImage from '../../Assets/scss.svg';

const skills = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Pug',
    image: pugImage,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'SCSS',
    image: scssImage,
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is that your `Assets` folder is not public. If you move the images from `Assets` to `public/images`, you will see the background will start working -

You have two options now -

`import` the image

```
import background from "../../Assets/pug.svg";
backgroundImage: `url(${background})`
```

OR

use `require`

```
backgroundImage: `url(${require("../../Assets/pug.svg")})`
```

Answer (score 0):

Change backgroundImage to background

```
{
    skills.map(skill => (
        <motion.div className='column' key={skill.id} variants={container}>
           <div className='skill'>
             <div className='skill-image' style={{ background: `${skill.image}`  }}/>
             <h3>{skill.title}</h3>
           </div>
        </motion.div>
      ))
   }
```